# applying function to dataframe; timestamp.dt

Tags: python, pandas

Ultimately I want to calculate the number of days to the last day of the month from every date in `df['start']` and populate the `'count'` column with the result.

As a first step towards that goal the `calendar.monthrange`
method takes (year, month) arguments and returns a (first weekday, number of days) tuple.

There seems to be a general mistake regarding applying functions to dataframes or series objects. I would like to understand, why this isn't working.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import calendar

def last_day(row):
    return calendar.monthrange(row['start'].dt.year, row['start'].dt.month)
```

This line raises an AttributeError: "Timestamp object has no attribute 'dt'":

```
df['count'] = df.apply(last_day, axis=1)
```

this is what my dataframe looks like:

```
       start  count
0 2016-02-15    NaN
1 2016-02-20    NaN
2 2016-04-23    NaN

df.dtypes

start    datetime64[ns]
count           float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 10):

Remove the `.dt`.  This is generally needed when accessing a vector of some sort.  But when accessing an individual element it will already be a `datetime` object:

#### Code:

```
def last_day(row):
    return calendar.monthrange(row['start'].year, row['start'].month)
```

#### Why:

This `apply` calls `last_day` and passes a Series.

```
df['count'] = df.apply(last_day, axis=1)
```

In `last_day` you then select a single element of the series:

```
row['start'].year
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

## sample data
d = pd.DataFrame({'start':['2016-02-15','2016-02-20','2016-04-23']})

## solution
d['start'] = pd.to_datetime(d['start'])
d['end'] = d['start'] + MonthEnd(1)
d['count'] = (d['start'] - d['end']) / np.timedelta64(-1, 'D')
```