# Python: AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'

Tags: python, html-table, timestamp, apply

I am new to Python

I have a df- df_kpi_1, one of it's volume is df_kpi_1['YEAR_MONTH']

```
0       202004
1       201912
2       202002
3       201908
4       202001
         ...  
1115    201911
1116    202004
1117    202006
1118    201909
1119    201909
Name: YEAR_MONTH, Length: 1120, dtype: int64
```

I was trying to add another column as finical year, but get error

```
def FY(x):
    if pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y%m').dt.month.between(7,12).any():
        return pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y%m').dt.year +1
    else:
        return pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y%m').dt.year
df_kpi_1['YEAR_MONTH'].apply(FY)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-a8f657c9f50c> in <module>
      4     else:
      5         return pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y%m').series.dt.year
----> 6 df_kpi_1['YEAR_MONTH'].apply(FY)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-129-a8f657c9f50c> in FY(x)
      1 def FY(x):
----> 2     if pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y%m').dt.month.between(7,12).any():
      3         return pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y%m').series.dt.year +1
      4     else:
      5         return pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y%m').series.dt.year

AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Comment: Please use triple backticks `\`\`\`` to separate the code from the text. Look at [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and then edit your post accordingly. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26993692).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [applying function to dataframe; timestamp.dt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967780/applying-function-to-dataframe-timestamp-dt)